# Using a KubernetesPodOperator to run a Docker command that uses Airbyte's Salesforce connector to ingest a report

Tags: python, docker, kubernetes, airflow, airbyte

I am using the [Salesforce source connector for Airbyte](https://docs.airbyte.com/integrations/sources/salesforce/) to ingest a report from Salesforce. The ingestion itself can be done with a single Docker command (tested locally and it works):

`docker run --rm -v $HOME/internal-reporting/airbyte/airbyte-integrations/connectors/source-salesforce/secrets:/secrets -v $HOME/internal-reporting/airbyte/airbyte-integrations/connectors/source-salesforce/integration_tests:/integration_tests airbyte/source-salesforce read --config /secrets/config.json --catalog /integration_tests/configured_catalog.json`

The output of the command is an unformatted JSON. I am trying then use Python to apply some light transformations to the output, put in a Pandas dataframe, and load it into a Lakehouse table using Spark. I would like to use Airflow to orchestrate the entire process from running the Docker command to writing the DF to the table. I believe the way to do this is with a `KubernetesPodOperator`, but I am unsure of how to mount the `secrets/config.json` and the `integration_tests/configured_catalog.json` files to the Kubernetes pod and package the command into the `KubernetesPodOperator`, and then subsequently pass the output of the Docker command to Python.

Here is the relevant code snippet from what I have so far:

```
def get_salesforce_data(raw_data):
    logging.info("Requesting Salesforce Opportunity Report.")

    opportunity_schema = psType.StructType(
        [
            psType.StructField("Id", psType.StringType(), True),
            # ... rest of schema ...
            psType.StructField("End_Date__c", psType.ByteType(), True),
        ]
    )

    df = pd.DataFrame()
    df = pd.read_json(raw_data, lines=True)

    record_df = df.loc[(df["type"] == "RECORD")]

    opp_df = pd.DataFrame(record_df["record"].values.tolist())

    report_df = pd.DataFrame(opp_df["data"].values.tolist())

    # write the Dataframe to the lakehouse

    logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

    output = subprocess.run(["hostname", "-i"], capture_output=True)  # nosec
    hostname = output.stdout.decode().strip()
    spark = (  # noqa
        SparkSession.builder.config("spark.driver.host", hostname)
        .config("spark.executor.instances", 2)
        .config(
            "spark.kubernetes.container.image",
            f"{os.getenv('SPARK_IMAGE')}:{os.getenv('SPARK_IMAGE_TAG')}",
        )
        .getOrCreate()
    )

    spark.sql("create database if not exists reporting")

    spark.conf.set("spark.sql.execution.arrow.pyspark.enabled", "true")
    spark_df = spark.createDataFrame(report_df)
    spark_df.write.format("delta").mode("append").saveAsTable("reporting.opportunities")

    logger.info("Table successfully written.")

docker_command = [
        "docker",
        "run",
        "--rm",
        "-v",
        "/project/airflow/source-salesforce/secrets:/secrets",
        "-v /project/airflow/source-salesforce/integration_tests:/integration_tests",
        "/project/airflow/source-salesforce",
        "read",
        "--config",
        "/secrets/config.json",
        "--catalog",
        "/integration_tests/configured_catalog.json",
        "-it",
        "salesforce_ingest",
    ]

default_args = {
    "owner": "airflow",
    "depends_on_past": False,
    "email": 
    "email_on_failure": False,
    "email_on_retry": False,
    "retries": 0,
    "retry_delay": timedelta(seconds=30),
}
with DAG(
    # DAG details
) as dag:
    # Get data from Salesforce
    docker_ingest = KubernetesPodOperator(
        task_id=f"ingest_salesforce",
        namespace="airflow",
        name="salesforce_ingest",
        image="airbyte/source-salesforce:latest",
        cmds=docker_command,
        dag=dag,
    )

    ingest_salesforce = PySparkOperator(
        task_id=f"load_opportunity_report",
        python_callable=get_salesforce_data,
        num_executors=2,
        op_args=[docker_ingest.output],
    )

    # assign task dependencies

    docker_ingest >> ingest_salesforce
```

The error I currently receive is:
`unable to start container process: exec: "docker": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown`

I believe that I'm not using the Docker command correctly in the `KubePodOperator` and that I should mount the secrets and catalog as volumes, and then the actual `cmd` operator should just be `read` with the rest of the arguments in `args`. I'm also not sure how to translate the paths on my local machine to Git paths. Any suggestions would be appreciated, thank you!